# Select first and last row for each group

Tags: sql, join, clickhouse

I want find delta between first row and last row `value` for each group in my SQL query, but sub-query for each run is always return different values in `time_last` and `last_value` column .
Please help me fix my query.

table1 containts uniq time values and duplicated name and value.
something like this:

```
time                    name        value
2023-01-16 08:52:51.965 apple       1100.0
2023-01-16 08:52:23.665 apple       691.3
2023-01-16 08:52:01.915 apple       107.0
2023-01-16 08:51:33.621 apple       1000.0
2023-01-16 08:51:11.815 apple_two   50.0
2023-01-16 08:50:51.574 apple_two   61.9
2023-01-16 08:50:42.575 apple_two   69.0
2023-01-16 08:50:21.800 apple_two   94.0
```

Problematic sub-query:

```
SELECT groupArray(time)[-1] as time_last, name , (groupArray(value)[-1])  as last_value
        FROM stage.table1 il 
        WHERE     time >= '2023-01-16 08:08:15'
            AND   time <= '2023-01-16 08:54:00'
            AND name like '%apple%'
            GROUP BY name 
        ORDER BY time_last
```

The totals query I want to use:

```
SELECT name, (last_value - first_value) as delta
    FROM 
    (SELECT groupArray(time)[1] as time_first, name , (groupArray(value)[1])  as first_value
    FROM stage.table1 il 
    WHERE     time >= '2023-01-16 08:08:15'
        AND   time <= '2023-01-16 08:54:00'
        AND name like '%apple%'
        GROUP BY name 
    ORDER BY time_first
    ) as frst  
    JOIN 
    (SELECT groupArray(time)[-1] as time_last, name , (groupArray(value)[-1])  as last_value
    FROM stage.table1 il 
    WHERE     time >= '2023-01-16 08:08:15'
        AND   time <= '2023-01-16 08:54:00'
        AND name like '%apple%'
        GROUP BY name 
    ORDER BY time_last ) lst on frst.name = lst.name 
    having name like '%apple%'
```

returned values:
first run:

```
time_first          name        first_value             time_last               `lst.name`  last_value  delta
2023-01-16 08:08:15.010 apple   1100                    2023-01-16 08:29:04.804 apple       1000        -100
```

second run:

```
time_first          name        first_value             time_last                           `lst.name`  last_value  delta
2023-01-16 08:10:44.813 apple   200                     2023-01-16 08:53:59.782 apple       254         54
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
create table t(time DateTime64(3), name String, value Float64) Engine=Memory as 
select * from values(
('2023-01-16 08:52:51.965','apple',       1100.0),
('2023-01-16 08:52:23.665','apple',       691.3),
('2023-01-16 08:52:01.915','apple',       107.0),
('2023-01-16 08:51:33.621','apple',       1000.0),
('2023-01-16 08:51:11.815','apple_two',   50.0),
('2023-01-16 08:50:51.574','apple_two',   61.9),
('2023-01-16 08:50:42.575','apple_two',   69.0),
('2023-01-16 08:50:21.800','apple_two',   94.0));


SELECT
    name,
    max(time),
    min(time),
    argMax(value, time) AS last,
    argMin(value, time) AS first
FROM t
GROUP BY name

┌─name──────┬───────────────max(time)─┬───────────────min(time)─┬─last─┬─first─┐
│ apple     │ 2023-01-16 08:52:51.965 │ 2023-01-16 08:51:33.621 │ 1100 │  1000 │
│ apple_two │ 2023-01-16 08:51:11.815 │ 2023-01-16 08:50:21.800 │   50 │    94 │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴──────┴───────┘
```